# PHP: The form values are not correctly passed to the handler script

Tags: php

I am using the hidden.php to pass two values to the "hidden_handler.php" for them to be displayed on a webpage. The two variables being used are $user and $time in the hidden.php . However, when they are passed over to the hidden_handler.php, the two values are shown as
" $user" and "$time"and not their assigned values , which are "Hunt" and the actual time.

I have tried to figure out for quite a while but could not find out what is the cause of it.  Thanks in advance for any valuable feedback.

Below are the two files with their code.

**hidden.php**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set(' UTC ');
$time = date(' H:i, F j');
$user = 'Hunt';
?>

<form action = "hidden_handler.php" method = "POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Send us your comments</legend>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="comment">
        </textarea>

        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="$user">
        <input type="hidden" name="time" value="$time">


    </fieldset><p><input type="submit" ></p></form>
?>
```

**hidden_handler.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
} else {
    $comment = NULL;
    echo 'You must enter a comment';
}

$time = (!isset($_POST['time']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['time'];

$user = (!isset($_POST['user']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['user'];

if (( $comment != NULL ) &&
        ( $time != NULL ) && ( $user != NULL )) {
    echo "<p>Comment received :\" $comment\" <br>
                                        From $user at $time </p>";
}
?>
```

When the hidden.php is run and I key in the comment as "test"
while $user and $time are hard-coded [ *$user = 'Hunt' and $time = date(' H:i, F j')*  ].

And the result is as shown below:

> Comment received :" test"
>   From $user at $time

Comment: Hint: use your browser to peek in the source of your generated HTML. You'll see `value="$user"`.

Comment: No, just.srad, please do NOT post on Stack Overflow @Mawg, please don't ask people to post again on a different site; the current question will be migrated if people vote for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $user;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo $time?>">
```

Using just quotes in HTML sees the values inside as strings, they are not interpreted as PHP variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="$user">
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="$time">
```

you are doing it in HTML, not in PHP, so those values are taken literally - the variables are not substituted.

You need to

```
<?php
   echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"user\" value=$user>"
   echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"time\" value=$time>"
?>
```

Comment: Or, for better readability, I feel, just use PHP blocks in the HTML: `<input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $user ?>">` (Also note that in the answer above, quotes are missing for `value=$user` and `value=$time`. Both the answer and my comment need some encoding as well, just in case `$user` holds funny characters.)

Comment: Then feel free to mark it as the answer, to help others who see it in future